Does it make sense to define a set using a property that is not defined for all the possible values of its argument?
This is a merely formal question. I'll explain with an example: say I want to denote the set of all the real numbers which have a reciprocal greater than $1$. I would write it like this:
$$S = \left\{x\in\Bbb R:\frac1x>1\right\}$$
The problem is, the statement
$$\frac1x>1$$
doesn't make sense when $x=0$, since $1/0$ doesn't have a value, thus it can't be compared to a real number. So, being completely formal, if I want my set to be well-defined I should write
$$S = \left\{x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}:\frac1x>1\right\}$$
since, otherwise, the proposition $0\in S$ wouldn't really make sense. Is this correct?

Yes. Nothing much more to say.

@JeanAbouSamra do you mean yes to the title question, or to the final question "is this correct"?

It is correct: the expression ${x ∈ ℝ : \frac{1}{x} > 1}$ doesn't make sense.

This question is similar to: Is this a valid set definition?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

While only the second suggestion $$\left\{x\in\Bbb R{\setminus}\{0\}:\frac1x>1\right\}$$ is well-defined, I suppose that in most informal settings it is acceptable to write $$0\not\in\left\{x\in\Bbb R:\frac1x>1\right\}$$ and read it as

it is not the case that $0$ is a real number whose reciprocal exceeds $1.$

Of course, we could alternatively just write $$S=\left\{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0<x<1\right\}=(0,1).$$

I would never write and never expect to see the first displayed statement in this answer.

The statement is formally wrong, since the set builder part still  asks for division by $0$. I meant the second expression. The point of the question is not whether $0$ has an inverse, it's how to write the set of reals whose inverse is greater than $1$. The first displayed expression in this answer is the answer. It's the second one I object to. It's formally wrong and useless.

Yes, the OP's first suggestion isn't rigorously correct.

A chatroom discussion regarding the acceptability of the statement $0\not\in\left{x\in\Bbb R:\frac1x>1\right}.$

To the downvoters who cannot tolerate the statement $0\not\in\left{x\in\Bbb R:\frac1x>1\right},\tag*{}$ observe that the (arguably) well-defined statement $\forall x{\in}\mathbb R{\setminus}{0};\frac1x\ne5\tag*{}$ merely abbreviates $\forall x{\in}\mathbb R;(x\ne0\implies\frac1x\ne5),\tag*{}$ which asserts, in particular, that $0\ne0\implies\frac10\ne5.\tag*{}$

If your notation creates ambiguity, improve your notation to remove ambiguity.
That's for communicating with people. If you are writing formulas to feed to a computer program, consult the manual for that computer program.
